# Get the best program support on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

My primary system is Ubuntu but I need to run some Windows programs that cannot be run on Wine. Given that Windows XP is very light-weight and can be downloaded (almost) legally, I want to get the most out of it. The problem is that most programs have already dropped support for XP and refuse to even install. Is there a way to disguise it as eg. Windows 7? The minimum would be changing the "header" of the OS, so that applications would think it's actually Win7. But if it was possible install some fancy 3rd-party updates to maximize app support, or even replace some dlls with their Windows 7 version, it would be much cooler.

**EDIT**: I tried changing the entries in [`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648796/currentversion-value-in-registry-for-each-windows-operating-system) but Windows Installer is not that easy to fool.

I own a legal copy of Windows 7, so I can use some files from there. This question is supposed to be more of a proof-of-concept. Of course I can install Win7 to VirtualBox (and probably will). But I'm searching for something light-weight that could run more apps than Wine. And of course hoping to get a deeper understanding of how Windows XP works.

Thanks for all your advice!

Note: If this smells "opinion-based" to you, stick with the "change header" part of this question :)
But I guess it's not opinion-based because there are not gonna be more ways to do it (if any).

Comment: The last time I tried to update Windows XP it took the better part of a day to do. The update-finding algorithm in XP is hopelessly broken and there is absolutely no incentive to fix it.

Comment: The time to get the most out of XP ended in 2014. Now it's a sitting duck for everything nasty if connected to the internet even if only minutes. It can compromise your own data and everybody else's because the question is not *if*, it's *when* it will be hijacked and act like a bot wreaking havoc somewhere. Please be socially responsible and, honestly, I expect better from an Ubuntu user ;)

Comment: The way to install bits of Windows 7 to maximise support is to run the Windows 7 installer and let it do it's job. That way you get all the compatibility of Windows 7 without any of the downsides of Windows XP. You cannot simply replace bits of XP with similar bits from 7 because most of them are interdependent and rely on other bits being the correct versions. By the time you've gotten everything happy with each other you'll be 30 years older, have lost your wife and effectively have installed Windows 7 by hand one single file at a time.

Comment: Is there a good reason why should this question get so many downvotes? Yeah, I know, there are much better and safer ways to do that. But that doesn't automatically make this a bad question.

Comment: Well the mouseover note mentions "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." Which might be an indication that people believe you have not researched how difficult (or aggravating) the problem is or that somehow kludging bits of Windows 7 into Windows XP is ultimately useless and fruitless when you can just use Windows 7 properly. Or it could just be that people have a pathological hatred of Windows XP. Or Tim Post [just lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/159016). Again.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP 64 bit is not a good choice.  Windows XP 64 bit is really Windows Server 2003 under the hood and you will find compatibility to be an issue.  XP 32 bits is a better choice than 64.  And both versions are end-of-lifed.

Windows 7 should be the best choice, as you can run modern applications and most XP programs in compatibility mode.